# View Size of Flink State Maintained By Each Operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, rocksdb

I use Flink1.8 for java to perform stateful calculations. My state is stored in RocksDB. Is it possible for me to determine the size of the state being maintained by each of my operators? My intent is to automatically/regularly report the total state size of each operator and trigger an alarm if they change dramatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this endpoint in Flink's REST API:

```
/jobs/:jobid/checkpoints/details/:checkpointid/subtasks/:vertexid
```

See the Flink 1.8 docs for more info: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/monitoring/rest_api.html#jobs-jobid-checkpoints-details-checkpointid-subtasks-vertexid