# Analyze Flink state size per operator

Tags: apache-flink

## Background

Our Flink state size is growing bigger. We're at around 1 TB per checkpoint and looking to optimize the state size. We'd like to analyze the space usage of the data that is stored in the state. For instance, find the biggest lists or maps.

## The question

How can Flink state size be analyzed per operator?

## Relevant reads

[View Size of Flink State Maintained By Each Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69654521/view-size-of-flink-state-maintained-by-each-operator) - Doesn't breakdown into the operator's state

[How Apache Flink Stores Your State data](https://towardsdatascience.com/heres-how-flink-stores-your-state-7b37fbb60e1a) - Doesn't provide a tool or method for space analysis

Answer (score 1):

The State Processor API can be used to analyze the contents of a savepoint.